# gRPC streaming procedure returning "Method is unimplemented." when running in Azure Container Instance

Tags: docker, .net-core, grpc, azure-container-instances

I have a gRPC service defined and implemented in dotnet core 3.1 using C#. I have a stream call defined like so:

```
service MyService {
    rpc MyStreamingProcedure(Point) returns (stream ResponseValue);
}
```

In the service it is generated

```
public virtual global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task MyStreamingProcedure(global::MyService.gRPC.Point request, grpc::IServerStreamWriter<global::MyService.gRPC.ResponseValue> responseStream, grpc::ServerCallContext context)
  {
    throw new grpc::RpcException(new grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode.Unimplemented, ""));
  }
```

In my service it is implemented by overriding this:

```
public override async Task MyStreamingProcedure(Point request, IServerStreamWriter<ResponseValue> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{ 
    /* magic here */ 
}
```

I have this building in a docker container, and when I run it on localhost it runs perfectly:

```
docker run -it -p 8001:8001 mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myservice.grpc:latest
```

Now here is the question. When I run this in an Azure Container Instance and call the client using a public IP address, the call fails with

> Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unimplemented, Detail="Method is unimplemented.")
>      at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

It appears that it is not seeing the override and is running the procedure in the base class. The unary call on the same gRPC service works fine using the container running in public ACI. Why would the streaming call behave differently on localhost and running over a public IP address?

Comment: How do you deploy the image? And do you mind sharing the image with me?

Comment: Unless your RPC is long lived, it is unlikely that streaming vs unary RPC would make a difference. At the HTTP2 protocol layer, both kinds of RPCs look the same. I think there's something very simple in your code that you missed. I think it's also likely that you are by accident talking to an old version of backend that doesn't have the code you think it has.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I get the same behaviour when running in a docker on my local machine.

Comment: Found the error myself. I have the proto file in a seperate project. This project uses Grpc.Tools as well as the server. These two need to match version (Grpc.Tools is used by Grpc.AspNetCore indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, because I had not registered service.

```
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<MyService>();
           
        });
```